# Как найти MBR в img файле

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, файловая-система

За основу своего проекта хочу позаимствовать части исходников [WinDiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

Открыв его исходники нашел там [такое](https://sourceforge.net/p/win32diskimager/code/ci/master/tree/src/mainwindow.cpp#l684):

```
    // Read MBR partition table
    sectorData = readSectorDataFromHandle(hRawDisk, 0, 1ul, 512ul);
```

Дальше идёт разбор считанного MBR, подсчёт сколько надо места и.т.д.

В конечном итоге данные [заливаются](https://sourceforge.net/p/win32diskimager/code/ci/master/tree/src/mainwindow.cpp#l752) в файл образа с расширением img.

```
if (!writeSectorDataToHandle(hFile, sectorData, i, (numsectors - i >= 1024ul) ? 1024ul:(numsectors - i), sectorsize))
```

Получил я реальный образ флешки, который прекрасно работает (записывается, и имеет правильную структуру).

Открываю файл hex редактором, и вижу следующее:

[image: Файл внутри]

Как видим, по указанным ранее адресам [0x1BE](http://lenovo-forums.ru/topic/9111-razmetka-pamyati-mobilnyh-ustroystv/#comment-253681) MBR нету ничего (нули). 
А по моему разумению (знаю, что не прав) должно бы быть.

Кто подскажет, где искать и как это вообще устроено в данном случае?